# How to optimize this matplotlib script and add spacing?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am new from matplotlib. May I know how to use loop function to plot this chart? Also, how to add spacing to the x-axis?

The code like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
%matplotlib inline

plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))

ax1 = plt.subplot(2,5,1)
plt.plot(tickers_data.index.strftime("%d"),tickers_data['Volume','XPEV'])
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
plt.title('XPEV')

ax2 = plt.subplot(2,5,2)
plt.plot(tickers_data.index.strftime("%d"),tickers_data['Volume','M'])
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
plt.title('M')

ax3 = plt.subplot(2,5,3)
plt.plot(tickers_data.index.strftime("%d"),tickers_data['Volume','MLCO'])
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
plt.title('MLCO')

ax4 = plt.subplot(2,5,4)
plt.plot(tickers_data.index.strftime("%d"),tickers_data['Volume','VIPS'])
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
plt.title('VIPS')

ax5 = plt.subplot(2,5,5)
plt.plot(tickers_data.index.strftime("%d"),tickers_data['Volume','HD'])
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
plt.title('HD')
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try calling `plt.tight_layout()` at the end?  Also note that `plt.subplot(2,5,1)` is the old interface to create subplots.  Using `fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 5)` is now the recommended way.  See e.g. https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html for an introduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,5)
for ax, y in zip(axs,['XPEV','M','MLCO','VIPS','HD']):
    ax.plot(tickers_data.index.strftime("%d"),tickers_data['Volume',y])
    ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
    ax.set_title(y)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Here are some explanations:

- `plt.subplots(nrows, ncols)` returns `Fig` object and `Axes` object (`array of Axes` if `nrows * ncols > 1`).
- Basically you want to draw your plots on each `Axes`. Thus, you loop over the `array of Axes` and plot your data `ax.plot()`.
- When you have multiple `Axes` drawn and it looks ugly, use `plt.tight_layout()`. It adds padding between `Axes`, making your figures look neat.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. After I read your answer, I tried to plot the second row of charts. I know I should use Nested loop, however, I still do not figure it out how can I do it.  May you please help me again?

Comment: @janicewww sure, I've added some explanations. Let me know if you need more explanations. Also checkout [this demo](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html) from matplotlib's documentation.

Comment: @Gusti Adli Thanks for your explanation. Yes, I hv read the documentation but I still unable to figure it out of how I can pass the value to second loop.

Comment: Hello, I figure it out now. Your help save my life. Thank you so much.

Comment: You should also try the more flexible constrained_layout: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html

Answer (score 0):

```
fig,((axs),(axs2),(axs3))  = plt.subplots(3,5,figsize=(15,6))

for ax, y in zip(axs,['XPEV','M','MLCO','VIPS','HD']):
    ax.plot(tickers_data.index.strftime("%d"),tickers_data['Volume',y])
    ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
    ax.set_title(y)

  for ax, y in zip(axs2,['LVS','PTON','SBUX','BLMN','NCLH']):
    ax.plot(tickers_data.index.strftime("%d"),tickers_data['Volume',y])
    ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
    ax.set_title(y)
    
      for ax, y in zip(axs3,['NIO','NKE','NKLA','NLS','QS']):
        ax.plot(tickers_data.index.strftime("%d"),tickers_data['Volume',y])
        ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
        ax.set_title(y)
```

plt.tight_layout(pad=0.4, w_pad=0.5, h_pad=1.0)
plt.show()

Comment: Please add more details to your answer such that others can learn from it - or is this something you wanted to add to your question, as this did not resolve the problem?